# Why do healthcare providers charge patients much more than the amount covered by the insurance in the United States?

Tags: united-states, health-insurance

Why do healthcare providers charge patients much more than the amount covered by the insurance?

If the amount covered by the insurance takes into account the amount of money healthcare providers charge, then why the latter isn't even higher?

If the amount covered by the insurance does not take into account the amount of money healthcare providers charge, then why the latter is so much higher than the amount covered by the insurance?

Example:

[image]

Comment: This is really not a personal finance question. And the details depend n what health the nsurance you have. The real answers are somewhere between politics and economics.. Healthcare services, like every other business, charge somewhere between what the market will bear and what's required to keep the business in operation. Insurance companies play the other side of that. Negotiated prices are often nonsensical, chosen just because they make those negotiations work.

Comment: There are no rational answers to questions about healthcare economics in the US.

Comment: @keshlam  I don't think the details depend on what health the insurance I have. I posted here as I saw some questions pertaining to understanding health insurances, e.g. [Why do insurance companies in the United States have an enrollment period?](http://money.stackexchange.com/q/26393/5656). Also understanding one's medical bills can be useful for personal finance (e.g., it would help see to what extent an uninsured patient may negotiate a medical bill).

Comment: If you want to ask about negotiability of medical bills, that's a different question. The only general answer to that he is "you can always try, but you should probably price-shopper ***before*** rather than try to change it retroactively.

Comment: It looks like this question is likely to be closed. The issue was touched on in my answer to [Hospital charges for ER visit](http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/66895/canadian-moved-to-us-hospital-charges-for-er-icu-visit). Not quite identical, to your "why" but still, an acknowledgement our system is broken.

Comment: The answer to "why" is a political question.  But to turn it around let's say you earn a salary that works out to 40 an hour.  Are you producing 50 of value evenly every single hour for your employer? (This past year, I had many low value days and a 20 hour stretch where I saved a big license from cancellation) Your employer is paying a bulk negotiated rate that on average is economical (otherwise you or they will eventually be out of business) and you have confidence you'll be able to meet your annual costs.

Comment: @user662852 I'm just trying to understand the factors that come into play for a pricing strategy between private entities, so I don't think the question qualifies as purely political. I think understand your reasoning on annual cost vs added value, I just don't understand why healthcare providers charge patients much more than the amount covered by the insurance.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer Thank you for the link, interesting. Yes, I'm trying to understand how broken it is, so as to minimize the financial impact on the patient.

Comment: Actually, I have just discovered I need a toilet valve repaired.  I could do this for myself (if I trust DIY.SO :D ) for $20 in parts and an afternoon.  If my building had a handyman, they might do it for me for a nominal fee or at cost (noting that I would otherwise pay the handyman some component of their full annual income through my condo fees).  If I call an emergency plumber, its going to be $350.  The insurance company = building handyman scenario.

Comment: @user662852 Does the amount covered by the insurance take into account the amount of money healthcare providers charge? (I'm trying to understand whether milking the patients is the only motivation).

Comment: This is not a question of politics.  You're just not going to get a solid informed answer.  Particularly because the industry is very complex.  The two answers are great examples of really poor assumptions about the economics of healthcare in the US.

Comment: Note that this is an arm's war. If a doctor knows the insurance company will only pay 10% of their nominal fee, it makes sense for them to multiply by 10 before filing. The insurance companies try to play the same game in reverse, when trying to get doctors to settle for what they are willing to pay. The result is that all the raw numbers are fictitious, and everyone knows they are, and somehow -- inefficiently! -- they make it work. True HMO, or single-payer, remove these perverse incentives to fabricate, but the insurance industry detests both.

Comment: I think the question may be backwards.  Ask instead why insurance companies only cover some fraction (typically 80-90%) of what health care providers charge (or why most policies have deductibles), and there's a fairly simple answer.  It's to (try to) keep people from running to the doctor for every least little thing, which they could readily treat themselves.

Comment: @jamesqf: I think deductibles are another question, as it it is typically a fixed amount e.g. 25 USD, regardless of how much health providers charge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The amount covered by the insurance takes into account the amount of money healthcare providers charge, according to this [Quora post by Amy Chai (MD)](https://www.quora.com/Why-do-doctors-charge-uninsured-patients-10-times-more-than-insured-patients-and-why-is-it-legal). For example, Medicare pays about 20 cents on the dollar for what a health provider bills. As a result, health providers have to artificially increase the amount of money they charge. Health providers cannot charge uninsured patients differently from insured patients, otherwise health insurances may complain to the feds, which in turn may charge the health providers with fraud for artificially inflating the medical bills.

Comment: Do you have evidence to support this? Are you suggesting that if my doctor charged $50 for the visit, that medicare would still pay 20% and send $10? My understanding is there's a 'reasonable and customary' which somehow doctor offices simply ignore and charge what they will.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer: Aside from the linked post, I do not. I would be very interested if someone could confirm or infirm the claim.

Comment: "Health providers cannot charge uninsured patients differently from insured patients" sure they can.

Comment: @quid Even if the patient doesn't negotiate?

Comment: For every billable event there is a corresponding ICD10 code.  When a provider agrees to an insurer's contract there will be a very very large table of reimbursements based on the provider's zip code and date of service for each code.  The same sort of table exists for medicare.  The allowed amounts can, and do, vary by insurer including medicare, they will also vary by provider.  No insurer, including medicare, pays a flat percentage of whatever the billed amount is.  The fraud complaint issue arises when a provider attempts to balance bill insured patients, not when retail prices fluctuate.

Comment: @quid I see. Well I have no idea who is correct between you and Amy. I opened a question on Law Stack Exchange: [Can a physician legally charge a patient for one ICD-10 differently depending on whether he is insured?](http://law.stackexchange.com/q/16016/31)

Comment: It's not really a question of legality.  It's a question of the medicare provider agreement.  Further, it's very common for insurers to specifically cover up to a multiple (200% or 300% etc) of the medicare amount for out of network reimbursements.  But to reiterate, the issue is balance billing.  Its a provider accepting a medicare (or other insurer) allowable amount according to their provider agreement as the billable amount, then attempting to recoup more money out of the patient.

Comment: For whatever it's worth this is the medicare fee schedule tool: https://www.cms.gov/apps/physician-fee-schedule/overview.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The price the provider charges you is the amount he would like to get for his services.
Let's take an example, you do a blood test at a lab, and they charge you 1200.00$

If you have insurance, and the provider has a contract with that insurance (meaning 'they take them'), the contract limits what they can charge and what the will get.
For the example, that might be 21.56$. This is what the insurance pays them (or what you pay them, if you have deductible).

Note that if you have no insurance, you owe them 1200.00$. They are typically willing to negotiate that you only pay maybe 850.00$, but it still will be much higher than the insurance price. Why?

The reason is that the insurance-agreed payment of 21.56$ does not cover their cost (but the insurance forces them to make that contract or basically be out of business). Let's say for example they need 26.56$ to make a living on it; so they lose 5.00$ on every *insured* customer. One in 235 customers has no insurance, and his price is calculated as 26.56+235*5.00 = ~1200.00$, so his bill covers the losses for all insured 'under-payers' (all numbers are examples made up to illustrate the math the provider does).

My bloodwork typically comes between 800 and 1400, and gets reduced to around 20: so the numbers are not completely off. The ratio and concept works for doctors and hospitals the same, just not as significant a difference.

Comment: I find it highly unlikely that the insurance payment "does not cover their cost". Many uninsured patients don't have the ability to pay (after all, if they could, they'd be paying for insurance), and the hospital will often eat those costs entirely.

Comment: @ceejayoz: Many uninsured people are (or were, prior to Obamacare) healthy people (for decades my only real expense was an annual FAA medical) with sufficient assets to cover any needed treatment.

Comment: Another unlikely assertion. People with enough assets to pay for a heart attack out of pocket aren't generally stupid enough to go without $1k/month of health insurance. Given that Obamacare saw 20 million of America's 44 million uninsured jumping onboard, I'm very dubious of that claim.

Comment: http://kff.org/uninsured/fact-sheet/key-facts-about-the-uninsured-population/  "In 2015, 46% of uninsured adults said that they tried to get coverage but did not because it was too expensive. Many people do not have access to coverage through a job, and some people, particularly poor adults in states that did not expand Medicaid, remain ineligible for financial assistance for coverage. Some people who are eligible for financial assistance under the ACA may not know they can get help, and others may still find the cost of coverage prohibitive."

Comment: and "In 2015, nonelderly uninsured adults were over two and a half times as likely as those with insurance to have problems paying medical bills (53% vs. 20%)... In 2015, nearly half (45%) of uninsured adults said they owed money on at least one medical bill."